# Psycopg2 - PGBouncer - Postgresql > Server does not support SSL but SSL was required

Tags: postgresql, python, pgbouncer, django

I've setup my Django application to use SSL while connecting to the Postgresql database via pgbouncer. I'm using Psycopg2 library.

I've done this before successfully, so I just did the same steps again.

But! After installing certificates to both servers and clients and making the installations, when I tried to run my application, I've got the error:

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required**

When I entered the command

```
psql --set=sslmode=verify-full -h DBHOST -p DBPORT -U USERNAME DBNAME
```

I can successfully connect to database by entering my password

But when I write the command like this;

```
psql "sslmode=verify-full host=DBHOST dbname=DBNAME port=DBPORT user=USERNAME"
```

or when I entered the code from python shell

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='DBNAME', user='DBUSER', password='DBPASS', host='DBHOST', port='DBPORT', sslmode='verify-full')
```

I got the stack trace;

```
/virtual_environment_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.pyc in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    128 
    129     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 130     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    131     if cursor_factory is not None:
    132         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

What may be the problem? I've compared the installated packages between previous installation which is succesful, versions of packages, certificates, file permissions etc. But I'm stuck in this issue.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the most silly answer, but when I changed my pgbouncer file, it worked like a charm.

```
client_tls_sslmode = verify-full
client_tls_key_file = /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/server.key
client_tls_cert_file = /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/server.crt
client_tls_ca_file = /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/rootCA.crt
```

part was just after the **[databases]** part, I moved it to  authentication settings part, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this command worked:

```
psql --set=sslmode=verify-full -h DBHOST -p DBPORT -U USERNAME DBNAME
```

Is that --set just creates a user-defined variable inside the `psql` program with the name of 'sslmode'.  That name is not special to `psql`, it does nothing with your connection options and you just connect without ssl.